# change the Click of a list item

Tags: android

in a listview, the click on every list item works only if i press the text in the list line...could it be possible to get action if i press wherever i like in the line and not only in the text of the line?thanks

```
 <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" android:mode="oneLine"
            />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should this to the layout XML of the TextView in your list row: android:focusable="false"